# What is the difference between a blurb and an abstract?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I'm a student of English Studies and I'm struggling with these two terms.

I know both are kinds of summaries, but I want to know the exact differences because I have to write an assigment using abstracts and blurbs as examples. I don't know what is best. I know what abstracts are used for, not so sure about blurbs. I would appreciate so much if someone could tell me.
Thank you!

Comment: abstracts are used to inform, blurbs are used to sell.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abstract and https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blurb

Comment: In addition to what @KillingTime says above, blurbs are also generally much shorter, designed to be glanced at rather than read with concentration.

Comment: I agree with what has been said so far.  *Blurbs* usually dwell on the inside jacket of hardcover books. *Abstracts* reside at the top of academic articles.

Comment: "Blurb" has developed several meanings.  Generally, I interpret it to be a variation on "blurt", implying that it's a wad of words that is not particularly well organized or well thought out.